# REST API eager or lazy?

Tags: json, rest

What is better? When a REST endpoint is queried for an entity - to return all the entities and sub-entities at once and then display them on the UI using some client side code (let's call it 'eager' mode), or it is better to return the main entity first and instead of its sub-entities, to return those sub-entities id's and then let the UI take care and issue the correct REST request for each id? (let's call it `lazy` mode).

So to return this JSON (this is actually not a valid JSON, just left the region: prefix for you to understand what entity it is):

```
country: {
 name: 'C1',
 regions: [
   region: {
      id: 'I1'
      name: 'R1',
      area: 'A1'
   },

   region: {
      id: 'I2'
      name: 'R2',
      area: 'A2'
   },
]

}
```

or this :

```
country: {
 name: 'C1',
 regions: ['I1','I2']
}
```

and then:

```
GET /rest/region/I1
GET /rest/region/I2
```

Which one is better? And when to use which? 
Thank you

Comment: The second is more "RESTful", but depending on how many subsequent api calls you have to make, you might want to do the former.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `"region"` key in your data. The `"regions"` list should already tell you that you have region objects.

Comment: Far from not needing a region key, it's actually not valid JSON at the minute...

Comment: This is all rather opinion-based, hence my close vote. Though, REST does not specify how you design your resources. You could let the client decide by simple content type negotiation. This would clearly be more RESTful then dictating what the client should get as response.

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, yes it's not valid JSON... It was only conceptual. I'll  edit the question to explain that it is not valid JSON but has the prefix for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a decision should usually be made based on need rather than trying to design everything up front. Think about who is using your service (you mention that it will be used from the UI) and what the requirements are.

Does the UI always need to load all of the data? If so, then lazy loading makes no sense at all and will just add complexity to your client side code. You can always implement 'lazy loading' at another URL later if you encounter performance issues or if you add another UI page that does not require all of the data.

If the UI by default only displays the 'top level data' and the more detailed information is only displayed conditionally based on some input from the user, then it would make sense to go for the 'lazy mode', as all of the data is not required all of the time.

In essence, write the UI code *before* you write the API. That will tell you which implementation makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends, doesn't it?

If the data is not going to change, you can go for eager loading.

If you are providing offline support, which means even when the user disconnects from the Internet you want your client to be working, eager loading is a must. It would need a well thought client side framework though.

If the data is frequently modified, it's better to do lazy loading.

If data is secured, then it's better to give it in small pieces rather than all at once but this is open to discussion.

In short, the rule of thumb is if your UI is smart and backend is dumb(er), go for eager loading, whereas if all the business logic lies on backend and UI is merely a representation, go for lazy loading.

Hybrid is not a bad idea either.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it or not, but something that I prefer.

- If the nested i.e. the inner model is relatively small, then I would prefer to use the "eager" mode. No point in doing one more API call to fetch the nested model. Keeping the network requests minimum is something I strive for.
- If the data from the nested model is to be displayed on the same screen or page then I would prefer the "eager" mode. Since I need the nested model information, let it come in the same API call. In this case it would not matter if the size of the nested model is huge. I need it any way!
- If the data from the nested model will be required in the subsequent screens or pages then you can use either "eager" or "lazy" mode by making a decision to use one API call that takes more time or a sequence of API calls each with relatively smaller times.

You can see that a lot of it depends on how the client app functions. So base your decisions on the need. Also try to keep API calls to a minimum. Network requests are expensive. But if any response is becoming too huge due to all the data from the nested model which you probably won't use unless the user performs some action, then break it into multiple API calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends. I would go with the first, as you can reduce the # of database calls, and the lagtime for what would be synchronized AJAX calls (you need to have the first return before making the second and third call).

The reason I say it depends, is because if there is a lot of data, or the first request takes significantly longer with the joins or extra data, you can keep the user placated with seeing the first result and let the remainders load while they are viewing the first result.

This also assumes the data is in a database and the user will definitely need the extra data.